# Sort list after numerical value in string

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list, where each item has the format "title, runtime" e.g. "Bluebird, 4005"

How can I sort that list in Python, according to the runtime part of the string for each item?

Is there a way to do this without using regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
words_list = ["Bluebird, 4005", "ABCD, 1", "EFGH, 2677", "IJKL, 2"]
print sorted(words_list, key = lambda x: int(x.split(",")[1]))
# ['ABCD, 1', 'IJKL, 2', 'EFGH, 2677', 'Bluebird, 4005']
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the first part has more than one word e.g. "Bluebird pt2, 4005". I should've specified that in the question. How can I modify your solution to fit the new criteria?

Comment: @D.Singh If your actual data has spaces in the middle, it might fail like that. I updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: The data did have spaces like that. But, it's working now! Thanks for the elegant solution.